# Refactoring on static Factory class where the other Factory class needs to use its private method

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, refactoring

In my code base there is an existing *ConnectionFactory* which is used in multiple places. I have recently added *AdvancedConnection* which is an extension of Connection class.
In the *AdvancedConnectionFactory*, in *CreateAdvancedConnection* I would like to use the template logic which is same as in *ConnectionFactory*. And then return the new instance of *AdvancedConnection* with options. My *AddTemplate* logic is big and I don't want to duplicate it. What would be the recommended way of using the *AddTemplate* logic in *AdvancedConnectionFactory*?

```
public static class ConnectionFactory
{
    public static Connection CreateConnection(Options options)
    {
        return new IntermediateMethod1(options);
    }

    private static Connection IntermediateMethod1(Options options)
    {
        AddTemplate(options);
        return new Connection(options);
    }

    private static void AddTemplate(Options options)
    {
        // do some templating stuff on the connection string
        options.ConnectionString = "some templated string";
    }
}

public static class AdvancedConnectionFactory
{
    public static AdvancedConnection CreateAdvancedConnection(Options options)
    {
        // Need to use the same logic of AddTemplate from ConnectionFactory
        return new AdvancedConnection(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would use a factory class if you're only returning instances of a single class (Connection). If Connection is a base class of AdvancedConnection, you should add code to ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection to return an instance of Connection 
 or AdvancedConnection based on the value of the options. That's what the factory pattern is for.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, this might be a better question for [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find a lot of ways to do it, but personally I would choose this approach:

```
public abstract class ConnectionFactoryBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if(_instance == null)
            _instance = new T();
        return _instance;
    }
    
    public abstract Connection CreateConnection(Options options);

    protected void AddTemplate(Options options)
    {
        // do some templating stuff on the connection string
        options.ConnectionString = "some templated string";
    }
}

public class ConnectionFactory : ConnectionFactoryBase<ConnectionFactory>
{
    public override Connection CreateConnection(Options options)
    {
        return IntermediateMethod1(options);
    }

    private Connection IntermediateMethod1(Options options)
    {
        AddTemplate(options);
        return new Connection(options);
    }
}

public class AdvancedConnectionFactory : ConnectionFactoryBase<AdvancedConnectionFactory>
{
    public override Connection CreateConnection(Options options)
    {
        return CreateAdvancedConnection(options);
    }
    
    public AdvancedConnection CreateAdvancedConnection(Options options)
    {
        AddTemplate(options);
        return new AdvancedConnection(options);
    }
}
```

(AddTemplate logic needs to be protected)

This is an example how it would work:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SkQC4E